# Can we send that particular column header of mat table to the api using which we are sorting the data

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, mat-table

Suppose I'm sorting the header by name so how can I send this header in the api for server side sorting

Comment: if you're using mat-table and mat-sort, you has the property "active" and "direction". If you want to see an example of API with a mat-table see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780213/connect-method-datasource-is-not-emitting-all-paginated-rows-for-mattable/63783274#63783274), in the comments there're a full example (well, the example has also filter and paginator, you can get only the part of sort)

Comment: but I have a form which contains some filters based on those I need to display the records and do the server side sorting and pagination it is not working in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Nar, take account that before use the "sort" you need that was in the view, so if you has under a *ngIf you need make a "work-aroud", see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776332/why-angular-table-didnt-sort/63783888#63783888). So before call your API you need know is the "header" is visible to get the "mat-sort

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.